# How to continue executing code after return

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm writing a short program using Google Apps Script that understands certain answers that a user inputs into a form then executes a few things.

At the moment my code takes too long to execute and the form response page is just an error - but it does actually do everything in the background.

What I really want to do is return the response for the function earlier, then continue executing the rest of the code - but I know that is impossible. Any ideas?

```
function doPost(e) {
  //get details from form
  var json = e.postData.contents;
  var obj = JSON.parse(json)

  var answers = getAnswers(obj);

  //do a few things...
  var parentID = createParent(answers);
  import(answers);


  textOutput = ContentService.createTextOutput('Form Success! you can log 
  in with ' + answers.username + ' and password Test1234')
  return textOutput
}
```

Comment: take a look at  JavaScript `Promise`. You can return from the function immediately and resolve the function asynchronously. Of course, there's no way to have the textOutput value before it is computed.

Comment: @dgeare Not really sure what you mean but `Promise` will definitely not turn blocking code into nonblocking one.

Comment: Use `HtmlService` and implement your solution as a webapp, sidebar, or modaldialog - all of which allow you to basically serve custom page(s) to the user, constructed from your `.html` files. You can call Apps Script server functions (in `.gs` files) based on user actions on said page, with client-side callback functions that get passed the server functions' `return` value. Read (a lot) more about `script.google.run`.

Comment: You would need to store the response by user and form question.  You can store data in Properties Service.  You'd need a scheme of naming the property keys the name of the user plus the name of the question, so that the correct previous response could be retrieved for that user and that question. Question 1 won't have a response ready to return.  So for question 1, you only need to make one function call.  So, you need to read about Properties Service, to store the response.  That's not hard

Comment: If you use an Apps Script Web App, and use `google.script.run`, that causes each instance of the function call to run independently.  Every `google.script.run` call runs it's own instance of the function.  So, you could make two different function calls, one to process the response, and one to get the previous response.  They can both run simultaneously without interfering with each other.

Comment: Did you ever get pass this?